# Взаимодействие с API ФНС России

Tags: php, xml, soap

Возникли проблемы с API налоговой. Они используют SOAP или что-то подобное, мозгов не хватает разобраться, в общем общение идет каким то образом через XML, а мне нужно писать на PHP. Читал что в PHP есть SOAP или можно отправлять XML через cURL, но я вообще не могу разобраться в этом во всем.

Мне нужно получить временный токен. 
В документации сказано:

> 5.1.1 Получение временного токена  Схема запроса для получения временного токена приведена в Приложении А. 
>   **Wsdl-сервис получения
>   временного токена должен быть доступен по адресу:
>   https://{OPENAPISERVER}/open-api/AuthService/0.1?wsdl**

Приложение А:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="urn://x-artefacts-gnivc-ru/ais3/kkt/AuthService/types/1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn://x-artefacts-gnivc-ru/ais3/kkt/AuthService/types/1.0" version="1.0">

  <xs:element name="AuthServiceFault" type="tns:AuthServiceFault"/>

  <xs:complexType name="AuthServiceFault">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Ошибка сервиса сообщений</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Message" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Сообщение об ошибке</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>   </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="AuthAppInfo">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Информация о внешнем приложении используещем публичные методы ФНС</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="MasterToken" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Мастер токен сгенерированный приложением с помощью выданого ключа</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>   </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="AuthRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="AuthAppInfo" type="tns:AuthAppInfo">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Данные необходимые для авторизации внешнего приложения</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>   </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="AuthResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Result">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Token" type="xs:string">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Токен сгенерированный для внешнего приложения</xs:documentation>
                      </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ExpireTime" type="xs:dateTime">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Дата и время истечения сгенерерированного токена</xs:documentation>
                      </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>       </xs:element>       <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Fault" type="tns:AuthServiceFault">       </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>   </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Я понимаю, что возможно тут всё очень просто, но я перерыл куча форумов и в голове дикая каша. Подскажите пожалуйста, может кто знает что, хотя бы небольшой пример кода. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Полный черновой пример работающего запроса (по состоянию на сегодня).
Необходимо вставить полученный мастер токен и обращаться с IP, на который был выпущен этот токен.

```
$ch = curl_init();

//ПЕРВЫЙ ЗАПРОС - получаем временный токен и вставляем его в заголовки следующих запросов
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://openapi.nalog.ru:8090/open-api/AuthService/0.1?wsdl",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns=\"urn://x-artefacts-gnivc-ru/inplat/servin/OpenApiMessageConsumerService/types/1.0\">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:GetMessageRequest>
    <ns:Message>\n<tns:AuthRequest xmlns:tns=\"urn://x-artefacts-gnivc-ru/ais3/kkt/AuthService/types/1.0\">
    <tns:AuthAppInfo>
    <tns:MasterToken>/*YOUR MASTER TOKEN HERE*/</tns:MasterToken>
    </tns:AuthAppInfo>
    </tns:AuthRequest>
    </ns:Message>
    </ns:GetMessageRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Content-Type: text/xml"
        ),
    ));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//echo $response;
echo $error;
//echo html_entity_decode($response);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($response);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('Token') as $element){
    $tempToken = $element->nodeValue;
}

$temptoken = $tempToken;

//ВТОРОЙ ЗАПРОС - отправляем всю информацию о чеке (в формате, как в примере) - и получаем messageId для третьего запроса
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://openapi.nalog.ru:8090/open-api/ais3/KktService/0.1?wsdl",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"
                 xmlns:ns=\"urn://x-artefacts-gnivc-ru/inplat/servin/OpenApiAsyncMessageConsumerService/types/1.0\">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:SendMessageRequest>
            <ns:Message>
                <tns:GetTicketRequest xmlns:tns=\"urn://x-artefacts-gnivc-ru/ais3/kkt/KktTicketService/types/1.0\">
                    <tns:CheckTicketInfo>
                        <tns:Sum>12500</tns:Sum>
                        <tns:Date>2020-04-23T12:08:00</tns:Date>
                        <tns:Fn>9287440300077658</tns:Fn>
                        <tns:TypeOperation>1</tns:TypeOperation>
                        <tns:FiscalDocumentId>166865</tns:FiscalDocumentId>
                        <tns:FiscalSign>4264393268</tns:FiscalSign>
                    </tns:CheckTicketInfo>
                </tns:GetTicketRequest>
            </ns:Message>
        </ns:SendMessageRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "FNS-OpenApi-Token: ". $temptoken ."",
        "FNS-OpenApi-UserToken: /*YOUR MASTER TOKEN HERE*/",
        "Content-Type: text/xml"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//echo $response;
echo $error;
//echo html_entity_decode($response);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($response);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('MessageId') as $element ){
    $messageId = $element->nodeValue;
}

$ch = curl_init();

//ТРЕТИЙ ЗАПРОС- получаем всю информацию о ранее запрошенном чеке. Возможны варианты - чек не будет найден, или запрос еще обрабатывается (статус - Processing).
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://openapi.nalog.ru:8090/open-api/ais3/KktService/0.1?wsdl",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns=\"urn://x-artefacts-gnivc-ru/inplat/servin/OpenApiAsyncMessageConsumerService/types/1.0\">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <ns:GetMessageRequest>
             <ns:MessageId>".$messageId."</ns:MessageId>
          </ns:GetMessageRequest>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "FNS-OpenApi-Token: ". $temptoken ."",
            "FNS-OpenApi-UserToken: /*YOUR MASTER TOKEN HERE*/",
            "Content-Type: text/xml"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    //echo $response;
    echo $error;
    //echo html_entity_decode($response);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($response);

    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('Code') as $element ){
        $code = $element->nodeValue;
    }
    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('Ticket') as $element ){
        $message = $element->nodeValue;
    }
    $x = json_decode($message, true);
    var_dump($x);
```

Comment: Если у кого перестало работать в декабре 20-го после обновления на стороне ФНС - необходимо заменить CheckTicketInfo на GetTicketInfo